# Como capturar mensajes de error del servidor y mostrarlos con un alert()?

Tags: html, angular, vscode

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web en Visual Studio Code y quisiera capturar los mensajes de error del servidor y lanzarlos con un alert(). Hay alguna forma de hacer eso? Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías mostrar parte de tu código, lo que intentaste hasta ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Donde hagas la suscripción a tu promesa agrega el catch del error ejemplo:

```html
  this.myRequest().subscribe(response=>{

    },error=>{

      //en esta variable queda tu mensaje
      error.message;

    })

   }
```

Para mostrar el alert elabora un popup o usa el alert de windows o descarga un paquete para esto como Angular material o Angular 2 Toasty o bootstrap, paquetes que ya tienen un gestor de alertas solo necesitas invocarlo.